# WP Rest API WP Rest Response возвращает двойные кавычки (один символ) вместо null при вызове метода класса

Tags: php, wordpress, json, api, wordpress-плагины

Делаю апи при помощи плагина WP Rest API. Столкнулся с такой проблемой.
Допустим у меня есть функция

```
function foo(){
    ...
    return new WP_REST_Response(null, 400);
}
```

если её вызывать как обычную функцию - все нормально, апи возвращает пустой ответ (content length = 0) и статус 400.
Однако стоит мне вставить эту же функцию в класс и апи почему то вставляет в ответ 1 символ двойных кавычек (content length = 1). В чем может быть причина и как от этого можно избавиться?

Код класса

```
class pdbcPlugin_Model {
        /*
            Constructor
         */
         
        public function __construct() {
            $this->pdbc_table_management_install();
            $this->pdbc_table_users_install(); //функции для создания таблиц в бд
        }

        public function pdbc_create_user(WP_REST_Request $request){
             global $wpdb;
             $managementLogin=$request->get_param('managementLogin');
             $managementPassword=$request->get_param('managementPassword'); 
             $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "management";
             if (empty($managementLogin) or empty($managementPassword)){
                  return new WP_REST_Response(null, 400);
             } else {
                  $rowcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE managementLogin = '$managementLogin' AND managementPassword = '$managementPassword' ");
                  if($rowcount==1){
                      $name=esc_sql($request->get_param('name'));
                      $email=esc_sql($request->get_param('email'));
                      $lastName=esc_sql($request->get_param('lastName'));
                      $password=esc_sql($request->get_param('password'));
                      $isPrivate=esc_sql($request->get_param('isPrivate'));
                      $isEnable=esc_sql($request->get_param('isEnable'));
                      if ( (empty($name)) or (empty($email)) or (empty($lastName)) or (empty($password)) or (!isset($isPrivate)) or (!isset($isEnable))){
                            return new WP_REST_Response(null, 400);
                      }else{
                            $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "projectusers";
                            $rowcount = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table_name WHERE email = '$email'");
                             if($rowcount==1){
                                  return new WP_REST_Response(false, 409);
                             }else{
                                  $wpdb->query( "INSERT INTO $table_name (id, name, lastName, email, password, isPrivate, isEnable) VALUES (UUID(), '$name', '$lastName', '$email', '$password', '$isPrivate', '$isEnable')" );
                                  return new WP_REST_Response(true, 200);
                             }
                      }
                   } else {
                       $response=array();
                       return new WP_REST_Response($response, 401);
                   } 
             }
        }  
}
```

Comment: Без вашего кода класса никто не угадает причину.

Comment: Обновил, добавив код класса

Comment: Приведённого кода мало. На каком хуке работает функция `pdbc_create_user`? А на каком вызывалась `foo`? Обычно все манипуляции с REST производят в классе, который расширяет WP_REST_Controller. А здесь мы видим некий висящий в воздухе класс.

Comment: И, кстати, null `new WP_REST_Response(null, 400);` возвращать не может, заголовок некорректный. `new ...` всегда возвращает экземпляр класса. А вот что вы потом делаете с этим объектом, хотелось бы увидеть.